# Undefined behavior of a program

Tags: c, arrays

While writing a program i am filling the entries of a char array with digits. After doing so the length calculated for an array having no zero is correct but for an array starting with zero is zero!

Why is this result coming so!I am not able to interpret my mistake!?

```
int main()
{
    int number_of_terms,no,j,i;
    char arr[100];
    char c;
    scanf("%d",&number_of_terms);
    for(i=0;i<number_of_terms;i++)
    {
        j=0;
        while(c!='\n')
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[j]);
            if(c=getchar()=='\n')
            break;
            j++;
        }
        printf("Length is:%d\n",strlen(arr));
    }
    return 0;
}

for eg if i input my array elements as 4 5
lenght is 2
and if my array elements as 0 5
length is 0..
```

Comment: And `c=getchar()=='\n'` is equal to `c=(getchar()=='\n')`, which you problably don't want.

Comment: whatever you declare please give it an initalizer. dont leave it floating. input might fail which will leave your variables in old state(which is undetermined per your code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using "%d" in your format specifier, which produces an integer, and you are passing in the address of a character array. This is, exactly like your title says, undefined behaviour. In particular, the value zero will take up 4 of the cells in your string, and will write zero to all of those. Since the character with value zero is the end marker, you get zero length string. However, on another architecture, the second character would probably cause a crash...

If you want to store integers in an array, you should use `int arr[...];`. If you want to store characters, use "%c".

Comment: Shouldn't pretty much any modern compiler catch that though?

Comment: Recent versions (within the last 10 years or so) of gcc, given enough warnings enabled will tell you that you are using the wrong format. Other compilers may or may not.

Answer (score 2):

You are copying the value 0 into the array. This eqals the character '\0' which is used to terminate strings. What you want is to copy the character '0' (has the value 48, see an ascii table).

Change %d to %c to interpret the input has character instead of decimal.

```
scanf("%c",&arr[j]);
```

Also your "string" in `arr` is not zero terminated. After all the characters of your string, you have to end the string with the value 0 (here a decimal is correct). `strlen` needs it, because it determines the length of the string by traversing the array and counting up until it finds a 0.